# Match repetition with regexp in ocamllex

Tags: regex, ocamllex

I'm trying to write a lexer with ocamllex for some special native language (that is a bit modified for my purposes). Some words shall be matched by their first char, that is doubled. But I dont find any way for express this repetition of the first char. Neither I can use the regex syntax

> (['a'-'z'])\1['a'-'z']+

with that "\1". Ocamllex says "illegal escape sequence \1." and I think thats really okay with the syntax of escape expressions, but sure thats not what I wanted. Nor I can use the repetition syntax with curly braces in any way (but this wont solve the problem anyway):

> ['a'-'z']{2}['a'-'z']+

I think there is a conflict with the oCaml code in the curly braces after the regexp.

Does anybody have an idea for that?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Ocamllex's regex doesn't have repetition syntax. The avaibable regex syntax is just as listed in reference manual:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/lexyacc.html#sec274

And I think you can manually list the all possible repetitions as below:

```
("aa"|"bb"|"cc"|"dd"|"ee"|"ff"| ..............)['a'-'z']+
```

Comment: thank you for validating my suspicions. :D thats not a really nice solution but a necessarry... oh Caml.